# console.log not printing the response

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a function that calls another function over the server and returns a string back which i want to be printed in the browser's log windows, The function looks like:

```
function getErrorInfo() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.getJSON('Get/ErrorInfo', function (responseText) {
            console.log("Log: "+responseText);
        });
    }, 5000);
}
getErrorInfo();
```

The function on the server sides does gets hits and returns a valid string But nothing is being displayed in the browser's windows Moreover the function on the server side must get hit after every 5 secs. but it only gets his on time and not again.

Please explain what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: What says the **network inspector** for the request?

Comment: You need to check the network tab in the console, and/or set a breakpoint in the script to inspect what `responseText` is. It only gets hit once because you appear to only call it once (why would it run again?). You can `setInterval()` instead, but I prefer to call `setTimeout()` again (here you can simply call `getErrorInfo()` again after the `console.log` call). Calling `setTimeout` again keeps the calls from stacking up.

Comment: @Adrian Preuß: It says `Status:200 OK`

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Understood the `setTimeout` thing but the main issue still exists nothing is getting printed.

Comment: Do you use firebug for debugging? it sometimes doesn't show the logged values. That why I don't use it anymore.

Comment: @undefined I am using `Chrome` > Console.. all other `console.log` calls are just fine.

Comment: What you should be looking for is the content of the response in the network tab. You should be able to see that by clicking on the entry.

Comment: @Maven You could also download a tool like Fiddler to track what your response is. Fiddler shows you the raw response which is nice. (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: @Jared Farrish: The `Network > Preview` tab does correctly shows the responded text, its just not getting printed in the console window, weired.

Comment: @Maven Could you include a sample of that text in your question? Its possible the JSON isn't properly formatted...

Comment: I see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Er5Lg/ I don't see anything wrong. What is the response text, verbatim? Add that to the question. Note I added the call to keep the error log info going.

Comment: @drew_w: Here: `3/8/2014 5:27:16 PMSystem.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at movie.Models.Genre.GetPosts(Int32 min)`

Comment: If that's your response (not JSON?), that would probably be your problem. It needs to be a JSON-formatted response for `$.getJSON()` to work. You could use a plain `$.get()` instead.

Comment: oh ok.. got it .. but what if i just wanted to return and print a string?
P.S. also please post this as an answer so i can accept.

Comment: Just use a plain `$.get()`, or `$.ajax()` and set the `dataType: plain`. Note, you also might put the next `getErrorInfo()` call inside the callback, I have it in the `setTimeout()` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `$.getJSON()`, the return result is required to be a valid `JSON` string, meaning it needs to be parsable into an object or array. In this situation, you can probably simply use `$.get()`, which will autodetect the return data type, or use `$.ajax()` and set the `dataType: plain` if you want to skip the JSON requirement.

On the second issue of keeping the log running, you can call `getErrorInfo()` from inside the `setTimeout()` or the callback, and it will keep running:

```
function getErrorInfo() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.getJSON('/echo/json/', function (responseText) {
            console.log("Log: "+responseText);

            getErrorInfo();
        });
    }, 5000);
}
getErrorInfo();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Er5Lg/

In my opinion, in this situation, it is better than `setInterval()`, since that can get backed up and end up overriding calls, and the errors might display out of order.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic issue is that you need to have properly formatted JSON in order to get back any result. Your result (per above) is:

```
3/8/2014 5:27:16 PMSystem.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at movie.Models.Genre.GetPosts(Int32 min)
```

Not only is this an exception text, but it isn't valid JSON. JSON format is fully [described here](http://json.org/). Rather than calling a real service, I would recommend starting by just getting a static JSON file from the server. Then you know the data is correct.

**Side Note:**
The other issue here is how you print the OBJECT result from `getJSON`. When you try to print an object using "Console.log" it converts it to a string, which isn't probably going to show what you want. You should probably change your log statement to:

```
console.log(responseText);
```

In chrome at least, the console window will let you browse the contents of the object which can be really helpful. Between the note and the solution above I think you should have it. Best of luck!

Comment: I think you might be confusing my jsfiddle with the OPs `responseText`, which is a text string (see the second-to-last comment so far). `console.log('LOG:', responseText)` would work as well (note the `,` instead of concatenation).

Comment: @JaredFarrish You are correct! I refreshed and didn't note that the OP wasn't posting the link. The issue is just the badly formatted JSON then. I will amend my result.